# Open cart send mail from model

Tags: php, email, opencart

I am using Opencart V2.0.1.1 for one project and i have a custom form in product page(.tpl). I want to send mail to store owner on submit of that form. I am able to process it and receiving the data till model but from model i am not able to send the mail and i am getting below error.

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < OK **Notice**: Undefined property:
>   Mail::$ErrorInfo in
>   **/opt/lampp/htdocs/dutees/catalog/model/catalog/product.php** on
>   line **784**{"success":"success"}

Below is my code

```
// CONTROLLER FUNCTION

public function getquote()
{
    $data = array(); $json = array();

    if (isset($this->request->post['name'])) {
        $data['name'] = $this->request->post['name'];
    } 
    if (isset($this->request->post['email'])) {
        $data['email'] = $this->request->post['email'];
    } 
    if (isset($this->request->post['mobile'])) {
        $data['mobile'] = $this->request->post['mobile'];
    } 
    if (isset($this->request->post['address'])) {
        $data['address'] = $this->request->post['address'];
    } 
    if (isset($this->request->post['description'])) {
        $data['description'] = $this->request->post['description'];
    } 
    if($this->config->get('config_email') != 'null' || $this->config->get('config_email') !='')
        $data['store_email'] = $this->config->get('config_email'); 

    if($this->config->get('config_name') != 'null' || $this->config->get('config_name') !='')
        $data['store_name'] = $this->config->get('config_name');

    $this->load->model('catalog/product');
    $gq_status = $this->model_catalog_product->sendQuote($data);

    if($gq_status = "success"){
        $json['success'] = "success";
    }else{
        $json['error'] = "Error : We are unable to send your request now, please use contact-us form";
    }
    $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
    $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));

}


// MODEL FUNTION

public function sendQuote($data = array()) {

    $status = ""; $name ="";$email ="";$mobile ="";$address ="";$description ="";

    if(isset($data['name']))
        $name = $data['name'];
    else
        $name = "Not Available";

    if(isset($data['email']))
        $email = $data['email'];
    else
        $email = "Not Available";

    if(isset($data['mobile']))
        $mobile = $data['mobile'];
    else
        $mobile = "Not Available";

    if(isset($data['address']))
        $address = $data['address'];
    else
        $address = "Not Available";

    if(isset($data['description']))
        $description = $data['description'];
    else
        $description = "Not Available";


    if(isset($data['store_email']))
        $store_email = $data['store_email'];
    else
        $store_email = "abc@def.net";

    if(isset($data['store_name']))
        $store_name = $data['store_name'];
    else
        $store_name = "Enquiry";

    $message = '
            <html>
            <body>
                <MY HTML MAIL CONTENT GOES HERE>
            </body>
            </html>
        ';

    $this->load->mail;

    $mail = new Mail();

    $mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
    $mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
    $mail->hostname = $this->config->get('config_smtp_host');
    $mail->username = $this->config->get('config_smtp_username');
    $mail->password = $this->config->get('config_smtp_password');
    $mail->port = $this->config->get('config_smtp_port');
    $mail->timeout = $this->config->get('config_smtp_timeout');            
    $mail->setTo($store_email);
    $mail->setFrom($email);
    $mail->setSender($store_name);
    $mail->setSubject("Product Get Quote");
    //$mail->setText("test message body text");
    $mail->setHtml($message);
    if(!$mail->send()) {
        $status = 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        $status = 'success';
    }

    return $status;


}

// VIEW AJAX 

<script>
$('#gq-submit').click(function(){
  var name=$('#gq-name').val();
  var email=$('#gq-email').val();
  var mobile=$('#gq-mobile').val();
  var address=$('#gq-address').val();
  var description=$('#gq-description').val();
  if(name != '' && email != ''&& mobile != '' && description != ''){
    $.ajax({
      type:'post',
      url:'index.php?route=product/product/getquote',
      dataType: 'json',
      data:'name='+name+'&email='+email+'&mobile='+mobile+'&address='+address+'&description='+description,
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('#gq-submit').button('loading');
    },  
    complete: function() {
        $('#gq-submit').button('reset');
    },
    success: function(json) {
      $('.alert-success, .alert-danger').remove();
      $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');

      if (json['error']) {
          $('#gq-showcheck').after('<div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> ' + json['error'] + '</div>');  
      }

      if (json['success']) {
         $('#gq-showcheck').after('<div class="alert alert-success"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> ' + json['success'] + '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');
      }
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      console.log(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
    }
  });}else{
      $('#gq-showcheck').after('<div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> ' + "Please fill all the fields" + '</div>');  

    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send mail, maybe the mail settings are incorrect and
the Opencart own Mail class hasn't any ErrorInfo field inside it. 
See: system/library/mail.php 
First of all set the the correct mail parameters and don't use $mail->ErrorInfo because it doesn't exist. When error occured during sending mail it calls a trigger_error.

Comment: Thx Istvan.. I took out the ErrorInfo also deleted  $this->load->mail; and it is working now.

Comment: @deeflor Please share your sample code